# Am I making too many http requests in angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, express

I have the following code in an angular controller:

```
  $scope.openCat = function(catId) {
    $http.get('/api/cat/' + catId).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.sortedArticles = [];
        var lst = data.articles;
        lst.forEach(function(n) {
          $http.get('/api/article/' + n).
            success(function(article) {
              $scope.sortedArticles.push(article);  
          });  
        });
      });
  };
```

As the categories collection in mongo is cross-referenced with the article collection, the http.get only returns article._ids. The idea is to display the article links by title per category, then I have another controller which deals with the individual article click and renders the content:

```
  $scope.articleClick = function(n) {        
    $http.get('/api/article/' + n).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.form = data;
      });    
  };
```

The code is all working as I would like but my question is: am I duplicating the http requests? or doing something else horribly wrong? please note I am completely new to this and just experimenting so I could be on the wrong track completely. Should I be using services for this? Thanks.

Comment: It's always better to minimize the number of HTTP Requests. Are you able to edit the backend eg. extend the api or add a controller which receives the catID and returns every article? This would reduce the number of requests to just 1.

Comment: It all depends on the kind of devices/platforms ou are targeting and the use pattern of your application. E.g. on mobile devices it is better to minimize the number of requests. On the other hand, if the user is usually expected to request 1-2 items, there is no reason to fetch 50 items in advance. So, there is always a trade-off. But it is rather easy to answer your question: The number of HTTP requests made from the controller should not exceed 0 ! All HTTP related stuff should be performed in services (this of course answers the "wording" of the question, not the "meaning" of it).

Comment: What is happening now is that I am fetching all articles in a category basically so that I can display the title of the article, which seems a bit wasteful.. ie if I or the user was happy seeing the article ID there wouldn't be a prob and every time would be 2 requests. I think an answer maybe, when adding an article to a cat, to add it as an array of [_id AND title]? Why do you say all http stuff should be in services?

Comment: I say controller shold not contain HTTP stuff (especially stuff that fetches data) because (according to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)**) that is not what controller are supposed to do. Controllers should just add behaviour to the `$scope` (i.e. implement the business logic of the app). Fetching/Sending data is a job better suited for a service (not to mention it makes it possible to share data accross controllers/views, keeping your code DRY). Not to even get started about how testability is impacted :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a good practice because if you got like 50 articles, your code is going to make 52 requests just for them. Always try to minimize the http requests because they're your bottleneck. A simple code of the backend will look like this:

```
app.get('/api/cat/:cat', function(req, res) {
    var catid = req.params.cat;

    ArticleModel.find({cat: catid}, function(err, data) {
        if ( err || !data ) {..}

        var output = [];

        data.forEach(function(i){
            output.push({
                title: i.title,
                id: i._id
            });
        });

        res.json(output);
    });
});
```

So you're sending a JSON array of the article's title and id only. Then with simple ng-repeat you can do:

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles">
     <a ng-href="article.id">{{article.title}}</a>
</div>
```

while handling the angular like this:

```
$scope.openCat = function(catId) {
    $http.get('/api/cat/' + catId).success(function(data) {
        $scope.sortedArticles = data;
    });
};
```

So only with 1 query, you got all the information you need.

And try to separate the API to services/factories. You can read more [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/).

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem I have is that I need the categories to be dynamic, ie the user will be able to move articles to differing categories at will, so my mongo category schema contains just an array of article IDs, to facilitate easy moving of articles. With your example and adding the title along with the ID as an array im sure can get it working smoother, thanks